# Can I query 285 IDs and URLs in a single elegantly formed SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have to query 285 IDs and paths. At first glance, there are no real patterns to the ID's and I'm not certain there's a way to achieve this end with a simple and elegant query.

However, I'm by no means an expert and still learning SQL. So, hoping for some guidance.

Below is an extract of the first 50 enttries i'm trying to match:

```
        ID  path
    261617  /About/Factfile
    31  /About/Factfile/18060
    761 /About/Factfile/18060/11550
    762 /About/Factfile/18060/11552
    763 /About/Factfile/18060/11555
    35  /About/Factfile/scotlandsnapshot
    63  /About/Government/background
    74  /About/Government/sgprevious
    1555    /About/Government/sgprevious/2007-2011
    328782  /About/Government/sgprevious/2011-2016
    1553    /About/Government/sgprevious/sgprevious1999-2003
    1554    /About/Government/sgprevious/sgprevious2003-2007
    46  /About/Information/expenditure
    271169  /About/Information/expenditure/GPC
    329992  /About/Information/expenditure/GPC/epc500-16-17
    297247  /About/Information/expenditure/GPC/GPC
    297249  /About/Information/expenditure/GPC/GPC/GPC
    297243  /About/Information/expenditure/GPC/GPC500
    271168  /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k
    1550    /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k/background
    1551    /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k/reports
    22138   /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k/reports/2011-2012
    291275  /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k/reports/expenditure
    22137   /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k/reports/Expenditure2010
    266779  /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k/reports/reports
    303729  /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k/reports/Test
    316271  /About/Information/expenditure/over-25k/reports/Test1
    276826  /About/Information/expenditure/PSRA2010
    293815  /About/Information/expenditure/PSRA2010/2011-12-PSRduties
    318093  /About/Information/expenditure/PSRA2010/duties-13-14
    311621  /About/Information/expenditure/PSRA2010/duties-2012-13
    294347  /About/Information/expenditure/PSRA2010/historic-efficiency-reports
    276831  /About/Information/expenditure/PSRA2010/historicexpenditure10-11and11-12
    261611  /About/People
    23769   /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements
    148038  /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements/2008
    148037  /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements/2009
    148036  /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements/2010
    148039  /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements/201112
    268177  /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements/2012-13
    296737  /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements/2013-14Engagements
    304646  /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements/2014-15Engagements
    317634  /About/People/14944/Events-Engagements/MinisterialEngagements/MinisterialEngagements
    987 /About/People/14944/Special-Advisers
    254426  /About/People/14944/Special-Advisers/gifts-hospitality
    1048    /About/People/14944/travel
    23479   /About/People/14944/travel/airtravel
    23481   /About/People/14944/travel/ferrytravel
    23483   /About/People/14944/travel/MinisterialCarJourneys
    148029  /About/People/14944/travel/MinisterialCarJourneys/2010-11
```

Should this be split into 2 queries, 1 for the ID's and another for the paths?

Thank you all in advance and please forgive me if this is n00b stuff.

Kind regards,

V

Comment: From your question, it's hard to answer. I would go with 1 query: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM TABLE_B )` But of course, we would need more info to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, path
    FROM tbl
    ORDER BY path
    LIMIT 285;
```